# How to improve performance of Laravel query builder when using a custom query

Tags: laravel, database-performance, laravel-query-builder

When searching for the topic `How to increase performance on Laravel`, I found a bunch of things but when it comes about `database`, allI could find was **Eager Loading**.

But how do we increase database query performance when using `query builder` and custom queries?
When I say *Custom Query* I mean a query really complex full of joins and `subQuery`.(Which I believe can't be replicated using `Eloquent`).

I believe there is no need to post the query since I'm not trying to find a bug, I just need some guidance about `How to increase performance` in this scenario? What could I try to do?

Working with legacy application, can't change much about the query.
Currently, my query is 15~17 seconds.

Comment: You can subquery a relationship with eloquent. The problem is that eloquent may not be as fast as the DB in cases of extreme complexity or size. This problem is probably better solved by using pagination.

Comment: We need to see the query to have an idea of the level of complexity. Anyway, if your query is for statistics, then you can't optimise it with Eloquent (most of the times) if not, using the relations might be more performing (depends on what you expect as result)